# Gower distance with R functions; "gower.dist" and "daisy"

Tags: r, clustering, distance, gower-similarity

I have 9 numeric and 5 binary (0-1) variables, with 73 samples in my dataset. I know that the Gower distance is a good metric for datasets with mixed variables.

I tried both daisy(cluster) and gower.dist(StatMatch) functions. We can assign weights in both fuctions; I assigned weights like that; 5 weights for numeric attributes and 1 for binary ones.

But they give different distance matrixes. Shouldn't they give the same results?
These are my features and first sample.

```
A    B      C   D   E   F   G   H    I       J       K   L       M       N  
800 1200    0   0   0   0   1   2   0.31    0.33    0.1 0.62    0.35    0.44
```

A; Numeric (Square feet)
B; Numeric (Dollar)
C-D-E-F-G; Binary (Yes-No)
H; Numeric (Number of children)
J-K-L-M-N Numeric (Percent)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They in fact do give the same results.  I am not sure how you are comparing them but here is an example:

```
# Create example data
set.seed(123)
# create nominal variable
nom <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], each=10))
# create numeric variables
vars <- as.matrix(replicate(17, rnorm(30)))
df <- data.frame(nom, vars)

library(cluster)
daisy.mat <- as.matrix(daisy(df, metric="gower"))

library(StatMatch)
gower.mat <- gower.dist(df)

# you can look directly to see the numbers are the same
head(daisy.mat, 3)
head(gower.mat, 3)

# now identical will return FALSE, why?
identical(daisy.mat, gower.mat)
> identical(daisy.mat, gower.mat)
[1] FALSE

# This is because there is of extremely small differences 
# in the numbers returned by the different functions
max(abs(daisy.mat - gower.mat))
> max(abs(daisy.mat - gower.mat))
[1] 5.551115e-17

# Using all.equal has a higher tolerance threshold
all.equal(daisy.mat, gower.mat, check.attributes = F)
> all.equal(daisy.mat, gower.mat, check.attributes = F)
[1] TRUE
```

Now that I understand you are adding an extra component to the `daisy` function there is still a solution.  It lies in the documentation for `gower.dist`.  The key part is in the first part of the documentation, namely that **columns of mode *logical* will be considered as binary asymmetric variables**.  So you want to make sure your data structure is appropriate.

```
set.seed(123)
# create nominal variable
nom <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], each=10))
# create binary variables
bin <- as.matrix(replicate(5, rep(sample(c(0,1), 30, replace=T))))
# create numeric variables
vars <- as.matrix(replicate(9, rnorm(30)))
df <- data.frame(nom, bin, vars)

# You can see that the columns are not 'logical' types
# We need to change this
str(df)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  15 variables:
     $ nom : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ X1  : num  0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...
     $ X2  : num  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
     $ X3  : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...
     $ X4  : num  0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
     $ X5  : num  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
     $ X1.1: num  1.026 -0.285 -1.221 0.181 -0.139 ...
     $ X2.1: num  -0.045 -0.785 -1.668 -0.38 0.919 ...
     $ X3.1: num  1.13 -1.46 0.74 1.91 -1.44 ...
     $ X4.1: num  0.298 0.637 -0.484 0.517 0.369 ...
     $ X5.1: num  1.997 0.601 -1.251 -0.611 -1.185 ...
     $ X6  : num  0.0597 -0.7046 -0.7172 0.8847 -1.0156 ...
     $ X7  : num  -0.0886 1.0808 0.6308 -0.1136 -1.5329 ...
     $ X8  : num  0.134 0.221 1.641 -0.219 0.168 ...
     $ X9  : num  0.704 -0.106 -1.259 1.684 0.911 ...


# make columns logical
df[,2:6] <- sapply(df[,2:6], FUN=function(x) ifelse(x==1, TRUE, FALSE))

# now the columns are the correct types
> str(df)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  15 variables:
     $ nom : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ X1  : logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
     $ X2  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ X3  : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
     $ X4  : logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
     $ X5  : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
     $ X1.1: num  1.026 -0.285 -1.221 0.181 -0.139 ...
     $ X2.1: num  -0.045 -0.785 -1.668 -0.38 0.919 ...
     $ X3.1: num  1.13 -1.46 0.74 1.91 -1.44 ...
     $ X4.1: num  0.298 0.637 -0.484 0.517 0.369 ...
     $ X5.1: num  1.997 0.601 -1.251 -0.611 -1.185 ...
     $ X6  : num  0.0597 -0.7046 -0.7172 0.8847 -1.0156 ...
     $ X7  : num  -0.0886 1.0808 0.6308 -0.1136 -1.5329 ...
     $ X8  : num  0.134 0.221 1.641 -0.219 0.168 ...
     $ X9  : num  0.704 -0.106 -1.259 1.684 0.911 ...


# now you can do your calls
daisy.mat <- as.matrix(daisy(df, metric="gower", type=list(asymm=c(2,3,4,5,6))))
gower.mat <- gower.dist(df)

# and you can see that the results are the same
all.equal(as.matrix(daisy.mat), gower.mat, check.attributes = F)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Determan. Yes, they gave the same results if I do not specify in "daisy" function that my binary variables are asymmetric. So "daisy" got them as Interval. As I understood we cannot specify variable type to "gower.dist" function.

Comment: @EmrahBilgiç, Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Dr. Determan, you can see my data below my question. I can not specify my binary variables in "gower.dist" function I think. First code for gower.dist function: > gower.dist <-gower.dist(mydata) And second code for daisy function: > daisy <- daisy(mydata,metric="gower",type=list(asymm=c(3,4,5,6,7)))

Comment: Dr.Determan, as I understood, both fuctions are automatically making the required standardation for my mixed type variables.

Comment: @EmrahBilgiç, see above, you can in fact specify binary variables with `gower.dist`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, They give the same result, just as proven by cdeterman.

One different I want to mention here is "gower.dist" actually use some kind of equal weights method (what they called weights in the function documents can only be 0 or 1), but "daisy" allow you to pass your weight vector by argument 'weights'.

Conclusion:
If you want a more flexible way to calculate Gower Dissimilarity, I prefer using "daisy" from package "cluster".
If you your main interest is building a synthetic dataset, use "gower.dist", it will save you a lot of time by direct using "NND.hotdeck".